# please create fps -> framerate tag synonym

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-naming

Someone recently created [fps](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fps). We already have [framerate](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/framerate). It'd be good if [fps](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fps) were merged into [framerate](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/framerate), please.

(I know there's a process by which non-mod users can propose tag synonyms and they may eventually become reality, but it's tedious and awkward and effectively doesn't work.)

Comment: Thanks, @MikeW!

Comment: Agree about non mods creating synonyms. It's a joke.

Comment: I thought fps/framerate was about videography and wasn't supposed to be discussed here?

Comment: @KohGeek In still photography, it's the way the speed of continuous drive is specified. In fact, merging into [tag:continuous-drive] might be an option.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. One more thing, is there a burst-shoot tag or something?

Comment: @KohGeek Look like we *also* have [tag:burst-mode]. That should probably be merged into [tag:continuous-drive] (creating an alias). Or the other way around — I don't have a strong opinion on which is the primary.

Comment: Many user will prefer burst mode as it's the usual terminology, in normal discussion I do say burst-mode more then continuous drive.

Comment: @KohGeek I'm not so sure about that. "Burst mode" maybe more common  now, but "continuous drive" is certainly the traditional term and AFAIK what most manuals will use. Also, there may be a slight distinction, as burst mode implies short-duration high-framerate capture, whereas continuous drive could mean that, or long-duration low-framerate (although not timelapse, but that boundary is blurry).